# I want to update the value json with php

Tags: php, json

Want to change some, such as description, change value to test2
form url json

```
{
  "title": "test",
  "description": "test",
  "keyword": "test",
  "ogimage": "test",
  "radio": "test",
  "noscript": "test",
  "fbpage": "test",
  "pagesID": "test",
  "payIMG": "test",
  "titlepay": "test",
  "font": "test"
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not good at English.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to edit specific JSON key values using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50444893/how-to-edit-specific-json-key-values-using-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this will help you

```
<?php 
$jsonString = '{
  "title": "test",
  "description": "test",
  "keyword": "test",
  "ogimage": "test",
  "radio": "test",
  "noscript": "test",
  "fbpage": "test",
  "pagesID": "test",
  "payIMG": "test",
  "titlepay": "test",
  "font": "test"
}';
$data = json_decode($jsonString, true);
$data['description'] = "test2";
$data = json_encode($data);
```

Comment: This is what I am looking for. Thank you.