# How to replace matching object on JSON in PHP?

Tags: php, json

In my code I want to replace the whole object with new values if the name match.

```
$data = file_get_contents('users.json');
$data = json_decode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
$dataMerge = array([
    "name" => $_POST['name'],
    "username" => $_POST['username'],
    "email" => $_POST['email'],
    "phone" => $_POST['phone'],
    "website" => $_POST['website'],
]);

$nameToUpdate = $_POST['name'];

for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) {
    $row = $data[$i];
    if ($row['name'] == $nameToUpdate) {
        $position = $i;
        break;
    };
}

$data = array_splice($dataMerge, $position);

// $json = json_encode($data);
$data = json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
file_put_contents('users.json', $data);
```

When you run this code it will delete all the objects on the json file and insert the new object. I just want to replace a certain object.

Comment: Are you looking to add a new record (insert a new user) or to replace an existing user? If you're looking to replace an existing under, what field should this be based on? The email? The username?

Comment: I want to match the 'name'. if it match it will be replaced with the new data from POST.

Comment: Why try to achieve this using array splicing - you already _have_ identified the element you want to replace, so just overwrite it? `$data[$i] = $dataMerge;` and done …?

Comment: Are you 100% sure that name is a unique identifier?

Comment: The second parameter to `json_decode` should be either true or false.

Comment: probable [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17806224/how-to-update-edit-a-json-file-using-php) or [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50444893/how-to-edit-specific-json-key-values-using-php/50444953)

Answer (score -1):

Based on your answer to my comment, there are few things to change:

1. The `array_splice` might not be the best solution here as you need to loop the array twice, while you can just do it once
2. The `$dataMerge` variable should just be an object, not an array with a single object.

See below the revised code

```
$data = file_get_contents('users.json');
$data = json_decode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
$dataMerge = [
    "name" => $_POST['name'],
    "username" => $_POST['username'],
    "email" => $_POST['email'],
    "phone" => $_POST['phone'],
    "website" => $_POST['website'],
];
foreach ($data as $key => $user) {
    if ($user['name'] == $dataMerge['name']) {
        $data[$key] = $dataMerge;
    }
}
$data = json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
file_put_contents('users.json', $data);
```