# PHP Modify JSON file with foreach

Tags: php, json, insert, decode

I have a json file:

```
$json='[{"Email":"myemail1@domain.com","Name":"company 1","Tel1":"xx-xx-xx","Adresse":"XXXXXX"},{"Email":"myemail2@domain.com","Name":"Company 2","Tel1":"xx-xx-xx","Adresse":"XXXXXX"}]';
```

and my forms post data in variable
vars="fname"=>"Ameur","lname"=>"KHIL"
"fname"=>"Marak","lname"=>"Cristo"

and I like to insert in between my json content with variable to get the final json like this:

```
$result='[{"Email":"myemail1@domain.com","Name":"company 1","vars":{"fname":"Ameur","lname":"KHIL","Tel1":"xx-xx-xx","Adresse":"XXXXXX"}},{"Email":"myemail2@domain.com","Name":"Company 2","vars":{"fname":"Marak","lname":"Cristo","Tel1":"xx-xx-xx","Adresse":"XXXXXX"}}]';
```

Comment: Please accept the given answer if it helped you.

Comment: duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50444893/how-to-edit-specific-json-key-values-using-php/50444953

Answer (score 2):

For this purpose you can use json_decode() to parse the JSON-String to a PHP-Object. Then you just set a new value vars to the given form values.

Parsing the JSON-String

```
$json = json_decode('[{"Email":"myemail1@domain.com","Name":"company 1","Tel1":"xx-xx-xx","Adresse":"XXXXXX"},{"Email":"myemail2@domain.com","Name":"Company 2","Tel1":"xx-xx-xx","Adresse":"XXXXXX"}]');
```

Adding the new vars value and removing the additional ones. This is just for the first entry but you can do the same for the other entry or even iterate through the array for multiple entries

```
$json[0]->vars = ["fname" => "Marak", "lname" => "Cristo", "Tel1" => $json[0]->Tel1,"Adresse" => $json[0]->Adresse];

unset($json[0]->Tel1);
unset($json[0]->Adresse);
```

And getting your result in a JSON-String

```
$result = json_encode($json);
```